# Run magento2.2.3 on Local Machine - MAMP

Tags: magento2, php, database, mamp

I downloaded my live magento 2.2.3 based website into my local desktop Mamp directory.

I imported the database into the local phpmyadmin.
I edited the app/etc/env.php file to have the correct localhost cridentials
for the phpmyadmin database

Now when i go to the website on http://mysite:8888
I get an error that says

```
Zend\Uri\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: no class registered for scheme "mysite" in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/vendor/zendframework/zend-uri/src/UriFactory.php:102 Stack trace: #0
```

so i am not sure what step I am missing to get a local version of the live site working.
I have My Mamp setup to use apache/php7.1.3/mysql5.6.38

Comment: Shouldn't you use 127.0.0.1 or localhost for local setup?